# Update the Old and New Value in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I have a problem updating the old value of the array in my redux react app. I have successfully updated the new selected object `true`. I want to other object to set to `false` since I have set the another object to `true`.

```
const initialState = {
  annualPlans: [],
};

const planReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case planConstants.UPGRADE_PLAN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        annualPlans: state.annualPlans.map((todo) =>
          todo.value === action.data.plan_id
            ? // transform the one with a matching id
              { ...todo, current: true }
            : // otherwise return original todo
              todo
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to re create **all** todo items, if you use pure components then that will mess up this optimisation. You can just add a map to deal with resetting the current value:

```
const planReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case planConstants.UPGRADE_PLAN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        annualPlans: state.annualPlans
          .map(
            (todo) =>
              todo.current
                ? { ...todo, current: false } //reset current to false
                : todo // no need to change this one
          )
          .map((todo) =>
            todo.value === action.data.plan_id
              ? // transform the one with a matching id
                { ...todo, current: true }
              : // otherwise return original todo
                todo
          ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to return `current` set to `false` for the others:

```
          todo.value === action.data.plan_id
            ? // transform the one with a matching id
              { ...todo, current: true }
            : // otherwise return with current false
              { ...todo, current: false }
```

Comment: You now re create **all** todo items, most of them you will needlessly re create and that can cause re renders or at least React having to re create jsx and having to deep compare the virtual DOM.

Comment: I agree it's not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Id first create the new todos by looping though a `map` and then assign to the state

```
case planConstants.UPGRADE_PLAN_SUCCESS: {
    const newTodos = state.annualPlans.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.value === action.data.plan_id) {
           return { ...todo, current: true }; // if todo.id matched then set the current to true and return;
        }

        if (todo.current) {
            return { ...todo, current: false }; // else if current is already true, then false it and return
        }

        return todo; // else return original todo
   });

    return {
        ...state,
        annualPlans: newTodos
    };
}        
.....
```

This will optimize the rendering and prevent of looping multiple times.